# Impersonate in IIs6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, access-denied, impersonation

We having a problem with our web server that it denies the access to shared folders, after some investigation I have notice that the 'WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name' returning the client side user name 'my User Name' instead of 'Network service'.

Now if I add following code into web config, the app works currently and uses 'Network service'.

```
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

My question is that, is there anywhere in the IIS6 that I can use/set to force all applications to using the 'Network service' user?

thanks in advance for the help,

Answer (score 0):

Set `impersonate="false` in the machine.config on the box. By default, the machine.config doesn't have `impersonate` on.

Comment: thanks for the response, I have already done this, but it does not working.